# Does pointwise convergence imply uniform convergence on bounded sets for linear operators?

Tags: functional-analysis, linear-transformations, banach-spaces

Let $X$, $Y$ be Banach spaces and $\{T_\alpha : X \to Y\}$ be a net of bounded linear map converging pointwise to a bounded linear operator $T : X \to Y$ and uniformly bounded in norm.

Then I remember vaguely that $T_\alpha$ converges to $T$ uniformly on bounded subsets of $X$. Is it correct? And how does one prove it? I think I have to use the linearity cleverly but cannot proceed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not true. If $H$ is Hilbert space with orthonormal basis $(e_n)$ then $T_n (\sum a_ie_i) = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} a_ie_i$ defines operators with $\|T_n|| \leq 1$ for all $n$. Also, $T_nx \to x$ for all $x$ but $\|T_n-I\|$ does  not tend to $0$.

[Uniform convergence on bounded sets is same as convergence in operator norm. In this example $\|T_n-I\|=1$ for all $n$].

Comment: Oh...Could you help me with "https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3378997/proving-that-composition-is-continuous-in-the-strong-operator-topology-when-the" ? I tried to use the nets to show the continuity..but am still stuck..

Comment: @Keith I have already seen that question but I don't quite understand what exactly the question is. If you could rewrite the question in simpler way I can try.

Comment: What is the part that you don't understand?? I just need to show that the composition of linear maps is continuous in the strong operator topology if the domain is bounded.